# Proving $|f'(\ell)|\le 1$ (?)

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is the following:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $x_0$ be a real number. Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. If $x_n\to\ell$ and $f'(\ell)$ exists, show that $|f'(\ell)|\le 1$.

By definition, we know $$\lim_{x\to\ell}\dfrac{f(x)-f(\ell)}{x-\ell}=f'(\ell).$$

Since we know the limit exists, can I consider the sequence of points $(x_n)$ and say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x_n)-f(\ell)}{x_n-\ell}=f'(\ell)$$ using the continuity of $f$ ? That way I can deduce $f'(\ell)$ is exactly one, which (I guess) is in general wrong (I haven't found a counterexample though).

Comment: Your argument, with some added material, will yield a proof. It *does not* give $f'(\ell)=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, you're right. I made an arithmetic mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $f(\ell)=\ell$. Then rewrite $\frac{f(x_n)-f(\ell)}{x_n-\ell}=\frac{x_{n+1}-\ell}{x_n-\ell}$. As $x_n\to\ell$, we have $|x_{n+1}-\ell|\le |x_n-\ell|$ for infinitely many $n$, which ultimately implies $|f'(\ell)|\le 1$.

Comment: I see the problem now. Thank you :)

Comment: what if $x_{2n}=(-1)^n/n, x_{2n+1}=0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of derivability,

$$
f(x_n) = f(l)+(x_n-l) f'(l) + o(x_n-l)\\
x_{n+1}-l = (x_n-l) f'(l)+ o(x_n-l)
$$

Now quantify the $o(.)$: let $r>0$.

$$
n\ge N\implies | o(x_n-l)|\le r\\
\implies |x_{n+1}-l| \ge |x_n-l| (|f'(l)|-r)
$$
Now if $|f'(l) |>1$, for $r$ small enough $|f'(l)|-r>1$ and then
$|x_{n}-l|$ is increasing from $N$. This is impossible because ot goes to $0$ and is positive.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Hagen's answer is the approach I was trying, so I chose that one. :)